# Remove button not work when changing the structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am adding buttons dynamically and it get added perfectly with this code and when i wanna remove the text boxes which user created by click on add more button works perfect.

The code in which button adding and removing perfectly on click event.

Here is the jquery script!.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var MaxInputs       = 8; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var InputsWrapper   = $("#InputsWrapper"); //Input boxes wrapper ID
    var AddButton       = $("#AddMoreFileBox"); //Add button ID

    var x = InputsWrapper.length; //initlal text box count
    var FieldCount=1; //to keep track of text box added

    $(AddButton).click(function (e)  //on add input button click
    {
        if(x <= MaxInputs) //max input box allowed
        {
            FieldCount++; //text box added increment
            //add input box
            $(InputsWrapper).append('<div class="controls"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="sub-category-name[]" required/><a href="#" class="removeclass">&times;</a></div>');
            x++; //text box increment
        }
        return false;
    });

    $("body").on("click",".removeclass", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        if( x > 1 ) {
            $(this).parent('div').remove(); //remove text box
            x--; //decrement textbox
        }
        return false;
    }) 
});
```

And here is Html.

```
<div class="form-group" id="InputsWrapper">
    <label for="sub-category-name">Sub Category Name </label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="typeahead"  name="sub-category-name[]" required>
        <a href="#" id="AddMoreFileBox" class="btn btn-info">Add More Field</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

But when i change the code structue a little bit than user can add the text boxes but can't remove the dynamically added text boxes .
Here is the Html code.

```
<div class="form-group" id="InputsWrapper">
    <div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control">
        <span class="input-group-btn"> <a href="#" id="AddMoreFileBox"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button">+</button></a> </span>
    </div>

</div>
```

and here is the script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var MaxInputs       = 8; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var InputsWrapper   = $("#InputsWrapper"); //Input boxes wrapper ID
    var AddButton       = $("#AddMoreFileBox"); //Add button ID

    var x = InputsWrapper.length; //initlal text box count
    var FieldCount=1; //to keep track of text box added

    $(AddButton).click(function (e)  //on add input button click
    {
        if(x <= MaxInputs) //max input box allowed
        {
            FieldCount++; //text box added increment
            //add input box
            $(InputsWrapper).append('<div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-btn"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default removeclass">X</a></span</div>');
            x++; //text box increment
        }
        return false;
    });

    $("body").on("click",".removeclass", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        if( x > 1 ) {
            $(this).parent('div').remove(); //remove text box
            x--; //decrement textbox
        }
        return false;
    }) 
});
```

Comment: Create a jsfiddle.net - pay attention to use "head" instead of "onload" in the fiddle

Comment: And validate your HTML. A should not wrap a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target your parents by tag and/or class name:

```
$(this).closest("div").remove(); // walk up the DOM until the nearest DIV
```

or

```
$(this).closest("div.form-group").remove(); // walk up to nearest div.form-group
```

Change form-group to the class of the container you wish to remove if I got the wrong container

Comment: thanks alot for putting your effort but my problem get solved with Fenex answer

Comment: No it did not. It got solved by the comment to a very wrong answer and if you change the structure again, your code needs to be modified, whereas my suggestion will work until you change the class or tag type of the container

Comment: brother i have used your structure as well and what its doing is removing all the textboxes belong to the form-group

Comment: I cannot see what the class is of what you need to remove since you have too much html in there. Change the classname to reflect the container you want to remove

Comment: but the first one works fine this one $(this).closest("div").remove() and the second one work horrible

Comment: Very happy. Have a great day

Comment: you are more than welcome and your answer is some how generic can work every where

Answer (score 0):

You need:
`$(this).parent().parent().remove();`

In second listing you changed structure HTML, but forgot about JS.

Your HTML was:

```
div
    a.removeclass
```

You added listener to a.removeclass, and you walk up the DOM-tree once:

```
$(this).parent('div').remove();
```

Your HTML now:

```
div
    span
        a.removeclass
```

Now, if you want to remove div, you need walk up the tree twice, but once!

Comment: Yes, I was wrong. I didn't pay attention to the add last listener.

Comment: the only error is in the second code is user cant remove the dynamically added text box and i am also trying to figure it out but the problem is something else

Comment: change
`$(this).parent('div').remove();`
to
`$(this).parent().parent().remove();`

Comment: start working please edit your answer and explain it although it works for me but there are other people which may get help also from your answer

Comment: I'm updating...
@Aitazaz Khan, and, in second script another mistake: where you adding input box:
</span**>**

Comment: @mplungjan, your version is better, i agree